# Bond Lengths in FCC, BCC and HCP Structures

Tags: crystal-structure, transition-metals

I was wondering what the crystal structures of FCC, BCC and HCP actually look like, and where atoms are placed in their configuration?

Specifically I'm looking at elemental nickel, iron and cobalt in their lowest temperature lattice type. (Below their curie temperature to be exact.)

Comment: If you do an [image google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=face+centered+cubic&tbm=isch) for something like FCC you get a bunch of pictures.  Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: No, You get a lot of bad diagrams that don't explain much about where the atoms actually are in the structure, and how to figure out their placement from the shape and lattice constants.